# Changes in the state of a data member trigger a change in the state of the overall object

Tags: c++, oop

I am new to OOP and I am probably misusing some terminologies here (in which case suggestion or edits are most welcome). I would like to know how to design classes so that under some pre-defined criteria, an update to a data member automatically triggers a change in some state in the overall object.

Let's consider the following pseudocode for a concrete but over-simplistic example. It is so simple that I don't need classes here but I hope it describes the type of problem.

```
class X {
private:
    int x;
public: 
    void update_x(int);
};

class Y {
private:
    std::set<X> xs;
    bool max_xs_at_least_10 = false;
public:
    void expand_xs() { xs.insert(X()); }
    void change_an_element_in_xs(){ call X::update_x on some element in xs }
};
```

Is it possible to implement `X::update_x` as follows?

```
void X::update_x(int y)
{
    x = y;
    if (x >= 10) {
        tell the instance of Y that contains this instance of X to 
        change max_xs_at_least_10 to true
    }
}
```

Comment: make `Y::max_xs_at_least_10` a function instead of a member variable, or put the code responsible for maintaining `Y`'s invariants in `Y::change_an_element_in_xs` instead of expecting `X` to know anything about `Y`

Comment: *"tell the instance of Y that contains this instance of X"* -- what if this instance of `X` is not contained in anything? Should your program blow up? (Hitting an issue like this often indicates a design problem. Sometimes it's a good idea to step back and rethink the approach.)

Comment: It's a bit confusing to have a class named `Y` and a parameter named `y` where the type of `y` is not `Y`.

Answer (score 0):

In simple case, when you sure that only one object should be notified about the change, you can simply hold a reference to the desired `Y` object:

```
class Y;
class X {
  private:
    int x;
    Y& _y;
  public:
   X(Y& y);
   void update_x(int val);

   bool operator<(const X& o) const { 
         // Objects has to be comparable to be used in std::set
         return x < o.x;
   }
};


class Y {
  private:
    std::set<X> xs;
    bool max_xs_at_least_10 = false;
  public:
    void expand_xs() { xs.insert(X(*this)); }
    void change_an_element_in_xs(){ /*call X::update_x on some element in xs*/ }
    void some_x_changed(int val) {
      if (val >= 10) {
        max_xs_at_least_10 = true;
      }
    }
};


X::X(Y& y) : _y(y) {}
void X::update_x(int val)
{
  x = val;
  _y.some_x_changed(val);
}
```

Note, that `X` shouldn't use `Y::max_xs_at_least_10` directly, because it violates *Encapsulation* OOP principle: `Y` should manage its state itself, `X` should only use `Y` public interface. That ensures, that changing internal `Y` logic won't cause changes in `X`.

In more sophisticated cases, for example, when it's possible that any other objects should be also notified about changing in `X`, it may be a good idea to use [Observer design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Simple implementation may look like:

```
class XObserver
{
public:
    virtual void x_updated(int new_x) = 0;
};

class X {
private:
    int x;
    std::vector<XObserver*> observers;

public:
    void add_observer(XObserver* observer) {
        observers.push_back(observer);
    }

    void update_x(int val) {
        x = val;
        for (auto observer : observers) {
            observer->x_updated(val);
        }
    }
    bool operator<(const X& o) const {
        // Objects has to be comparable to be used in std::set
        return x < o.x;
    }
};

class Y : XObserver {
private:
    std::set<X> xs;
    bool max_xs_at_least_10 = false;
public:
    void expand_xs()
    {
        X x;
        x.add_observer(this);
        xs.insert(x);
    }

    void x_updated(int new_x) override
    {
        if (new_x >= 10) {
            max_xs_at_least_10 = true;
        }
    }

    void change_an_element_in_xs()
    {
        //call X::update_x on some element in xs
    }
};
```

The idea is simple: if any other object should be notified, it's class should be derived from `Observer` class and implement `void x_updated(int)` method.
After that you can register a new observer using `X::register_observer(Observer*)` method.
After changing state of `X` every registered observer will be notified.

Note, that you should be careful with Observers lifetime: if `X` will be updated after one of observers is destroyed, you will get a crash.

This code just shows an idea: you may want to add `X::deregister_observer()` method, or use smart pointers -- it's up to you, your needs and creativity.
Good luck!

// UPD: Also note, that I addressed a generic idea of notifiying other objects about change; If your code really looks like that -- `X` is changed  only by calling `Y::change_an_element_in_xs()` it's a way simplier just to put your logic in this method.